# Selenium webdriver error Unable to find element on (bamboo)

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, bamboo

I am new to selenium and using Chrome webdriver.

The element I want to click is

```
<a href="/myclassroom/studentsclass" class="current">Students</a>
```

I wrote a little code to click on the link as

```
driver.findElement(By.(linkText("Students")).click();
```

Other ways I tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(a[@href="/myclassroom/studentsclass"])).click();
```

Above (Both) piece of code working fine locally on windows but when I push it on bitbucket where bamboo execute it. It returns error element not found.

What can be a possible reason for the error?
Thanks. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the browser it is run against in your CI ? It might be not rendering the element correctly or it might not interpret the element correctly. You can try using a css selector to if the issue is in element missing or in selenium

Comment: I had already tried with css selsctor but same issue .

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an issue of longer loading time on the server, add some wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Students"))).click();;
```

Comment: ok i am testing. i will respond right back after testing it. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me please that is there any difference between implicitlyWait and the above method written by you.

Comment: @RamzanMahmood `implicitlyWait` will wait for the element to exist in the DOM. Explicit wait (`WebDriverWait`) will wait for the ExpectedCondition (`elementToBeClickable` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list:

```
List<WebElement> elements= driver.findElement(By.id("current").findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (int j = 0; j <= elements.size(); j++) {
   if(elements.get(i).getText().equals("Students")){
      elements.get(i).click();
      break;
   }
}
```